# When creating a new user in Windiws server 2016, I get a blue screen with no options

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Windows server 2016. When I try to add a new user from my admin account, the user gets created successfully.

However, when I try to login as the new user, I get this blue screen with no options except the logout button when I click on the windows start button (On the top right).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeKhw.png)

How can I access normal windows desktop using the new user?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Windows Server 2016 Start button or Taskbar. Are you using some kind of third party software that modifies the Start button and Taskbar?

Comment: Uninstall any third party Taskbar software

Comment: No, for the admin user, it works fine and it is Windows Server 2016. Only for new user it appears like this. When I click on the Windows Start button it only gives me the option to  log out.

Comment: Check what groups new user is member of